# _com_ptr_t CreateInstance returns REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have an ATL project where I need to perform various initialization routines inside `CComObjectRootEx::FinalConstruct`. For demonstration purposes, consider the following implementation:

```
HRESULT FinalConstruct()
{
    return m_bInit ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
}
```

This should return the appropriate HRESULT to the caller, indicating whether the initialization of the object was successful.

However, the client always receives `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` instead of `E_FAIL` in case of failure, when trying to create the server:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#import <finalconstructtest.dll>

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);
    {
        finalconstructtestLib::IFCClassPtr p;

        // Returns REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
        hr = p.CreateInstance(__uuidof(finalconstructtestLib::FCClass));         
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I change the class context to `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` however, the intended HRESULT is returned correctly:

```
// Returns E_FAIL
hr = p.CreateInstance(__uuidof(finalconstructtestLib::FCClass), nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073488/c-sharp-com-dll-has-regdb-e-classnotreg-error-in-c-project) post, where a similar behavior could be observed. However, I can't seem to find any reason why the class context affects the return value of `FinalConstruct`. Is this intended and perhaps documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CoCreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615) API is not promising to forward the internal failure code to the caller. The implementation prefers to indicate the the source of the problem its own way, by returning `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` meaning that it was unable to complete instantiation. Which is in turn true: it indeed was unable to create an instance (and the problem is not, for instance, related to missing interface, marshaling, permissions etc.). That is, the API prefers to suppress internal failure code to replace it with a documented one.

If you prefer to indicate a specific instantiate failure, you are better off with succeeding with initial creating an instance, and then you can implement an interface with a property or method exposing status, or giving relevant `HRESULT` error (with or without `IErrorInfo` support etc).